# How do you deal with the edge of the table in tile laying games like Carcassonne

Tags: carcassonne

When playing a tile-laying game, like Carcassonne or Qwirkle, what rule should we use for reaching the edge of the table?

1. Play "off the table" is illegal
2. Play is legal, and we'll faff around moving tiles around to make things fit
3. something else?

Obviously the best answer is to play on a bigger table in the first place, but sometimes these things happen.  How does your group handle it?

Comment: Since, to the best of my knowledge, the rules don't cover that question, it's entirely up to your group how to handle that situation. The question is therefore entirely opinion-based.

Comment: "How do you do things?" does not have a single answer. Voted to close as this is not an appropriate question.

Comment: Would you prefer a "what rules do different games have to accommodate this?"  I know at least one game that specifically says the edge of the table is a limit.

Comment: Either you want the simple list you already provided, or you're expecting us to survey all games. Neither are acceptable.

Comment: Just narrow the scope to Carcassonne only. And ask if there is an *official* way to play instead of asking how each group plays.

Comment: You can also play on a large tablecloth do you can just move the tablecloth if you need to move the tiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everyone I play with leave it that if the piece can't sit there it can't be played there.  If you make the rules that you can't play 'off the table' then it becomes part of the strategy for playing.  Don't place meeple on things that can't be completed.  You can do what ever you want but this rule keeps things very simple and if everyone knows, then they can try to avoid getting themselves in a sticky situation.

Answer (score 4):

Everyone I play with move the tiles to accommodate when possible.

Answer (score 2):

In Carcassonne, the edge of the table is the edge of the world.  I thought it was in the rule book, but I can't find it.  Maybe it was in a BGG FAQ.

I can't think of a general rule.  In Bananagrams, where each person has his own tableau that he is constantly rebuilding anyway, you just moved your tiles as you need to, but that counts as part of your turn -- that is, everybody doesn't stop and wait for you.  If somebody finishes while you're adjusting, too bad.  I can't recall seeing it come up in Qwirkle or Qwirkle Cubes.